# GeoServer GeoCSS generates too many symbols

Tags: geoserver, style

Can anyone help me with the GeoCSS below, I don't understand why this generates 5 legend categories when I was expecting only 4 categories?

```
/* @title Monitor */
* {
    mark: symbol(circle);
    mark-size: 12px;
    :mark {
        stroke: black;
        fill: #00CC22;
    };
}

/* @title Warning */
[repair = 0][reading >= site_normal*1.4][reading < site_normal*1.8]:mark {
    fill: #cc9c00;
}

/* @title Alert */
[repair = 0][reading >= site_normal*1.8]:mark {
    fill: #cc0000;
}

/* @title Under Repair */
[repair = 1]:mark {
    fill: #ffffff;
}
```

That CSS generates this legend, I was expecting only 4 symbols and I don't want the "Monitor, Warning, Alert" symbol.

[image: legend]

Its almost a copy of this example, so I'm not sure why there is the extra symbol: http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/styling/css/tutorial.html#refining-the-style

Answer (score 1):

Alert and warning are not distinct so the symbolizer is generated even if it will not occur.

Comment: How could they be made distinct? My understanding of both the linked example and my css is that a feature can not be in two categories?